# Does anyone know what this piece is? 3224730, with a bar at right angles to two more-rectancular bits

Tags: part-identification

I found this piece and don't have any idea where it came from or what it would be used for. The number "3224730 2" is stamped on the side. For scale reference, the long round bar portion fits in a minifigure's hands.

[image][image]

Comment: Does it also have a LEGO logo stamped on it anywhere? My first guess is that's it's a sprue but it's hard to tell.

Comment: @NathanStohlmann No, it does not have LEGO stamped on it.  Maybe it's not LEGO?  The circular part is the same diameter as LEGO bars.  It was mixed in with all my other LEGO parts.

Comment: @NathanStohlmann Looking closer, there are some fine mold seams visible along the length which I would not expect on a LEGO part.  It seems like not being LEGO or being a sprue are probably good guesses.

Comment: The texture also doesn't resemble LEGO.

Comment: I'm somewhat skeptical about this piece being LEGO as well. However, the font is very similar to the one used by LEGO - all of the digits are the same on my LEGO elements. But then again, the number of digits (8+1) is just too much for any known LEGO element.

Comment: Long shot, but `3224730` matches the part number for a turn signal component used in a number of Chevy vehicles which is large enough to feasibly contain this part inside. Perhaps this is an internal part (specifically internal part #2)? Found the part number via [this Ebay listing](https://www.ebay.com/itm/194425695936) and it appears to be sold under a more [generic Chevy part number (20962250) elsewhere](https://www.amazon.com/General-Motors-20962250-Combination-Switch/dp/B00M38O5RG). I can't find any good diagrams and I don't have one to tear down to verify this hypothesis.

Answer (score -3):

This is not a Lego piece, If you look at the colour (or a trained eye does) This is probably a knock off lego set, as well as lego doesn't make these sort of pieces and lastly with every Lego piece ever made the have the icon, try to find it, If it isn't there it's a fake.

Comment: "every Lego piece ever made the have the icon" - that is **not** true!

Comment: Just to emphasize the previous comment, not all official LEGO parts have the LEGO logo on them. The vast majority do, but there are plenty of examples that do not.

Comment: How can you identify this is non-LEGO element by relying on it being made in Black color? It may be obvious with some other colors and color shades, but Black is a common color for lots of LEGO elements.